# If can set caption for images in this table?

Tags: tables, captions

If can set caption for 3 image in cells of table in this command? What abut For one image?

```
‎\documentclass[11pt,fleqn]{book}‎
‎%\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amssymb,amsthm}‎
‎\usepackage{graphicx}‎ 
‎\usepackage{capt-of}‎
‎\usepackage{caption}‎
‎\graphicspath{{./Pictures/}}‎
‎\begin{document}‎
‎\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|}‎
‎\hline‎
‎pic1&pic2&pic3\\‎
‎\hline‎
‎\includegraphics[scale=.2]{first.pdf}‎
‎%\captionof{figure}{ 1}‎
‎&\includegraphics[scale=.2]{second.pdf}‎
‎%\captionof{figure}{ 2}‎
‎&\includegraphics[scale=.2]{third.pdf}\\‎
‎\hline‎
‎%\captionof{figure}{ 3}‎
‎\end{tabular}‎
‎\end{document}
```

Comment: Well, actually the trick to get more than one image on the same line with its respective caption involves using the package [subfig](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/subfig)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, let's try to do the same you try with the code of your MWE:

‎

```
\documentclass[11pt,fleqn]{book}‎
‎%\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amssymb,amsthm}‎
‎\usepackage{graphicx}‎
\usepackage{subfig} 
‎\usepackage{capt-of}‎
‎\usepackage{caption}‎
‎\graphicspath{{./Pictures/}}‎
‎\begin{document}‎

\begin{figure}[htb]
\centering % A TeX command that is equivalent to the center environment but needs less memory. Ideal when you need to insert a lot of figures in a document.
\subfloat{
‎\includegraphics[scale=.2]{first.pdf}‎
‎}
\subfloat{
\includegraphics[scale=.2]{second.pdf}‎
‎}
\subfloat{‎
\includegraphics[scale=.2]{third.pdf}
‎}
‎\caption{General caption of the figure}‎
\label{fig:examples}
\end{figure}
‎‎\end{document}
```

I use yet the `subfigure` package that below the [CTAN](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/subfigure) is considered obsolete. But it's quite easy to do what you want using that package:

```
\documentclass[11pt,fleqn]{book}‎
‎%\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amssymb,amsthm}‎
‎\usepackage{graphicx}‎
\usepackage{subfig} 
‎\usepackage{capt-of}‎
‎\usepackage{caption}‎
‎\graphicspath{{./Pictures/}}‎
‎\begin{document}‎

\begin{figure}[htb]
\centering % A TeX command that is equivalent to the center environment but needs less memory. Ideal when you need to insert a lot of figures in a document.
\subfigure[caption 1]{‎\includegraphics[scale=.2]{first.pdf}‎}
\subfigure[caption 2]{\includegraphics[scale=.2]{second.pdf}‎‎}
\subfigure[caption 2]{‎\includegraphics[scale=.2]{third.pdf}‎}
‎\caption{General caption of the figure}‎
\label{fig:examples}
\end{figure}
‎‎\end{document}
```

Check both options and please read the documentation of those packages. I hope this will be useful.